# gensim most_similar with positive and negative, how does it work?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54581599/7339624) That says about Gensim `most_similar`:

> it performs vector arithmetic: adding the positive vectors,
> subtracting the negative, then from that resulting position, listing
> the known-vectors closest to that angle.

But when I tested it, that is not the case. I trained a Word2Vec with Gensim `"text8"` dataset and tested these two:

```
model.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])

>>> [('queen', 0.7131118178367615), ('prince', 0.6359186768531799),...]
```

---

```
model.wv.most_similar([model["king"] + model["woman"] - model["man"]])

>>> [('king', 0.84305739402771), ('queen', 0.7326322793960571),...]
```

They are clearly not the same. even the queen score in the first is `0.713` and on the second `0.732` which are not the same.

**So** I ask the question again, How does Gensim `most_similar` work? why the result of the two above are different?

Comment: It is expected. See https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/king-man-woman-king-9a7fd2935a85

Comment: FYI, I've implemented and replicated the `most_similar` results [here](https://github.com/viniciusarruda/word2vec).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adding and subtracting isn't *all* that it does; for an exact description, you should look at the source code:

[https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#LC690:~:text=def%20most_similar,self%2C](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#LC690:%7E:text=def%20most_similar,self%2C)

You'll see there that the addition and subtraction is on the *unit-normed* version of each vector, via the `get_vector(key, use_norm=True)` accessor.

If you change your use of `model[key]` to `model.get_vector(key, use_norm=True)`, you should see your outside-the-method calculation of the target vector give the same results as letting the method combine the `positive` and `negative` vectors.